# Error ENFILE never occurs on GNU/Hurd systems

Tags: c, gcc, glibc

I was reading the [GNU C Library Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/pdf/libc.pdf#Error%20Codes) and I found:

> int ENFILE
>
> “Too many open files in system.” There are too many distinct file openings in the
> entire system. Note that any number of linked channels count as just one file opening;
> see Section 13.5.1 [Linked Channels], page 354. This error never occurs on GNU/Hurd
> systems.

`This error never occurs on GNU/Hurd systems.` - Why?

Comment: The kernel table that records open files grows dynamically.  The system runs out of memory first.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That makes sense. Thank you. Could you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*As requested.*</sup>

The kernel table that records open files grows dynamically.  The system runs out of memory before it runs out of open file table entries.